# PHP Replace Special Chars

Tags: php, xml

I am running the below script and it gets the value of player from an XML Feed. If I run the code this way it replaces the é with an e,

```
                        $player = "Toré";
                        echo "Player Before: $player <br />";
                        $playerafter = strtr($player, $normalizeChars);
                        echo "Player After: $playerafter <br />";
```

But if I run it with the XML Feed it does not change

```
                        $player = "$event->player";
                        echo "Player Before: $player <br />";
                        $playerafter = strtr($player, $normalizeChars);
                        echo "Player After: $playerafter <br />";
```

Here is the variable $normalizeChars

```
    $normalizeChars = array( 
        'Á'=>'A', 'À'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'AE', 'Ç'=>'C', 
        'É'=>'E', 'È'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Í'=>'I', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ð'=>'Eth', 
        'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 
        'Ú'=>'U', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 

        'á'=>'a', 'à'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'æ'=>'ae', 'ç'=>'c', 
        'é'=>'e', 'è'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'í'=>'i', 'ì'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'eth', 
        'ñ'=>'n', 'ó'=>'o', 'ò'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 
        'ú'=>'u', 'ù'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ü'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 

        'ß'=>'sz', 'þ'=>'thorn', 'ÿ'=>'y' 
    );
```

Comment: So what is the question? What problems are you having?

Comment: `$player = "$event->player";` will only store: `Array->player` in it instead of the value inside the array/object.

Comment: if I use the unquoted version it still does not work

Comment: What output does it give you?

Comment: What does `echo "Player Before: $player <br />";` show?

Comment: Player Before 1 : Touré Y.
Player After 1: TourA� Y.

Comment: Where does `$event` come from? What is the XML encoding? What's your file encoding? What's your output encoding? There's clearly a wrong conversion somewhere. Make sure everything in the process is the same, ideally UTF8.

Comment: How do I change the XML to UTF8. I heard that simpleXMLElement should auto convert, but how do I check. The XML document is not defined and the PHP files output is set to UTF8

Answer (score -2):

force the xml to string.

```
$player = (string)$event->player;
```

Comment: `"$event->player"` **is** a string.